# Click listener of Bookmark image in my Custom List item, changes another row_item image many times

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

I have created one **Custom List View**. In List view every component have its click event like Add to Bookmark image, Current Location image, Distance Location image etc.

In Bookmark Image, e.g. suppose there are 10 rows visible in my screen, if I click on 4th row item bookmark image then sometimes it will change bookmark image above or below. I am posting my base adapter code here.

Thank you in advance.

Base Adapter

```
public class OffersBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
LayoutInflater mInflater;
OffersInformation offerList = new OffersInformation();
private MessageData msgData;
//String OfferId;

public OffersBaseAdapter(Context context, OffersInformation offerList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.offerList = offerList;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return offerList.offersInfo.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
//        return offerList.offersInfo.get(position);
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
//        return offerList.offersInfo.indexOf(offerList.offersInfo.get(position));
return position;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_HeaderOffer, tv_OfferDescr, tv_PostedBy, tv_Distance, tv_RemainingDays;
    ImageView img_AddtoWishBag, img_storeLocation, img_storeDirection, img_storeImage, img_vertical, img_horizontal;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    try {

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_item_offers, null);
            holder.tv_HeaderOffer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvC_ProdcutOffer);
            holder.tv_OfferDescr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvC_ProductDescription);
            holder.tv_PostedBy = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvC_PostedBy);
            holder.tv_RemainingDays = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvC_remaingTime);
            holder.tv_Distance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvC_distace);
            holder.img_vertical = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivC_Vertical);
            holder.img_horizontal = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivC_Horizonal);
            holder.img_AddtoWishBag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivC_addToWishBag);
            holder.img_storeImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivC_Logo);
            holder.img_storeDirection = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivC_mapView);
            holder.img_storeLocation = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivC_Location);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.img_AddtoWishBag.setTag(position);

        List<String> items = Arrays.asList(offerList.offersInfo.get(position).st_logo.split("\\s*,\\s*"));


        if (position == 0)

            if (position % 2 == 0) {

                holder.img_horizontal.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#019CD5"));
                holder.img_vertical.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#019CD5"));

            } else {


                holder.img_horizontal.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0A7B9B"));
                holder.img_vertical.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0A7B9B"));

            }

        holder.tv_HeaderOffer.setText(offerList.offersInfo.get(position).of_title);
        holder.tv_PostedBy.setText("Posted By : " + offerList.offersInfo.get(position).st_name);
        holder.tv_OfferDescr.setText(offerList.offersInfo.get(position).of_desc);


        String KM = String.format("%.02f", offerList.offersInfo.get(position).distance * 1.609344);
        holder.tv_Distance.setText(KM + " KM");
        holder.tv_RemainingDays.setText(offerList.offersInfo.get(position).of_end);


        holder.img_storeLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent reDirectMap = new Intent(context, AndroidGoogleMapsActivity.class);
                reDirectMap.putExtra("Latitude", offerList.offersInfo.get(position).st_lat);
                reDirectMap.putExtra("Longitude", offerList.offersInfo.get(position).st_lng);
                context.startActivity(reDirectMap);
            }
        });

        if (!offerList.offersInfo.get(position).st_logo.equalsIgnoreCase("") || !offerList.offersInfo.get(position).st_logo.equals("no")) {

            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(AppWSConstants.IMG_UPLOAD_OFFER_URL + items.get(0))
                    .into(holder.img_storeImage);
        } else {
            // holder.img_storeImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_icon);
        }


        if (offerList.offersInfo.get(position).is_wishbag.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {

            holder.img_AddtoWishBag.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_removefromwishbag);

        } else {

            holder.img_AddtoWishBag.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_addtowishbag);
        }


        final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
        holder.img_AddtoWishBag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (offerList.offersInfo.get(position).is_wishbag.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {

                    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                    params.put("loginid", AppGlobal.getFromUserDefaults(context, AppConstants.KEY_UID));
                    params.put("offerid", offerList.offersInfo.get(position).of_id);

                    AsyncHttpClient mClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
                    mClient.setTimeout(6 * 1000);
                    mClient.post(AppWSConstants.WS_ADDTO_WISHBAG, params, new AddRemoveOfferWishBag(finalHolder.img_AddtoWishBag, true));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();


                } else if (offerList.offersInfo.get(position).is_wishbag.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {

                    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                    params.put("loginid", AppGlobal.getFromUserDefaults(context, AppConstants.KEY_UID));
                    params.put("offerid", offerList.offersInfo.get(position).of_id);

                    AsyncHttpClient mClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
                    mClient.setTimeout(6 * 1000);
                    mClient.post(AppWSConstants.WS_REMOVEFROM_WISHBAG, params, new AddRemoveOfferWishBag(finalHolder.img_AddtoWishBag, false));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        Log.i("LogInfo->", ex.getMessage());
    }


    return convertView;

}


public class AddRemoveOfferWishBag extends AsyncHttpResponseHandler {

    ImageView ivWishBag;
    boolean isAddWishtoBag;

    public AddRemoveOfferWishBag(ImageView ivWishBag, boolean isAddWishtoBag) {


        this.ivWishBag = ivWishBag;
        this.isAddWishtoBag = isAddWishtoBag;

    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        super.onFinish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String content) {
        super.onSuccess(content);

        msgData = new MessageData();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type infoType = new TypeToken<MessageData>() {
        }.getType();
        msgData = gson.fromJson(content, infoType);

        if (msgData.messageInfo.status == 1) {

            if (isAddWishtoBag) {
                ivWishBag.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_removefromwishbag);

            } else {
                ivWishBag.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_addtowishbag);

            }


        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable error, String content) {
        super.onFailure(error, content);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: use settag inside if condition after adding all views

Comment: @Aayushi it's not work for me ... it shows me same problem

Answer (score 0):

You are now setting new on click listeners every time the `getView()` gets called. I think that messes up the functionality. I would place all the `setOnClickListener()` calls inside the `if (convertView == null) {...}` block so that the listeners are set up just once for each `ViewHolder` instance:

```
...
mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

if (convertView == null) {

    // The code block for one time initializations:

    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_item_offers, null);
    holder.tv_HeaderOffer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvC_ProdcutOffer);
    holder.tv_OfferDescr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvC_ProductDescription);
    holder.tv_PostedBy = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvC_PostedBy);
    holder.tv_RemainingDays = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvC_remaingTime);
    holder.tv_Distance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvC_distace);
    holder.img_vertical = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivC_Vertical);
    holder.img_horizontal = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivC_Horizonal);
    holder.img_AddtoWishBag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivC_addToWishBag);
    holder.img_storeImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivC_Logo);
    holder.img_storeDirection = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivC_mapView);
    holder.img_storeLocation = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivC_Location);

    // Set up all listeners here:
    // ...


    convertView.setTag(holder);

} else {

    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

holder.img_AddtoWishBag.setTag(position);

List<String> items = Arrays.asList(offerList.offersInfo.get(position).st_logo.split("\\s*,\\s*"));

// Set the latest content here. Don't do any initializations here as this code is always run.
// ...

...
```